# PlotLegends parameter with subscript and multiple of other parameter in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending, parameters, expression-form

[image]

```
PlotLegends ->  LineLegend[{Style[Subscript[ω, i] t == 0, Black]]
```

When I use this command in *Mathematica 13.2*, I get `t*Omega_{i}` instead of `Omega_{i}*t`.

**How can I tackle this?**

As can be seen in the attached image.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. You should put the whole working code in your question, and also use the button for code formatting. To answer the question, you can use [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html): ``Style[HoldForm[Subscript[ω, i] t] == 0, Black]``